# post method not working on condition

Tags: php

I have created a page on which a form posts its value. So I add some lines to get those values like

```
$parameter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Parameter']);
```

But when I open that page without that form it shows Notice that
Undefined index parameter in page on line.

So I want to make something like if I post the values then only specific area will work.
Otherwise remaining area will work just like if condition.

For ex.

```
if(post)
{}
else
{}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would need to check if the values are set properly..You can do it with the  if condition which would be like

```
if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('name_of_your_submit_input',$_POST)){
// do the things after form processing
}else{
//things you want to do after form breaks.
}
```

Comment: THanx :) I will accept your answer in shortwhile :)

Comment: But i didnt understand whats I have to write in place of 'name_of_your_submit_input'

Comment: parameter..the name which have u assigned to ur input

Answer (score 2):

Use `isset()` to check

```
if(isset($_POST['Parameter'])){
    //desired tasks
    //$parameter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Parameter']);
}else{
    //other task
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isset()` function. In your case if should be like

```
if(isset($_POST['param']))
{
 //Do something
}
else
{
 //Do something else
}
```